# É uma boa prática realizar imports dentro de métodos?

Tags: python

Existe alguma vantagem ao realizar `import` dentro de métodos ao invés de realizar a importação "tradicional" no cabeçalho do programa?

Caso eu realize a importação dentro do método, o módulo só será importado quando o método for chamado? Assim, o módulo é reimportado toda vez que o método é chamado?

Gostaria de saber em que cenário utilizar essa flexibilidade da linguagem é útil.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vamos por partes.
O guia de estilo usado pela maior parte das pessoas, o documento chamado PEP-8, recomenda que as importações sejam no cabeçalho do módulo.

MAS é preciso ter em mente que são recomendações de estilo e não ferro e fogo - o mais importante mesmo é entender o que acontece, e aí você verifica o que é melhor em cada ponto do seu projeto.

> o módulo só será importado quando o método for chamado?

Se o mesmo módulo não for importado em nenhum outro módulo ou lugar, sim, ele só será importado quando o método for chamado pela primeira vez.

> Assim, o módulo é reimportado toda vez que o método é chamado?

Não! Depois que um módulo é importado em Python, ele é mantido num registro interno (o dicionário `sys.modules`), e novas diretivas de importação para o mesmo módulo só criam novas variáveis, no contexto local, apontando para o módulo que já foi lido. Ou seja: em chamadas subsequentes ao mesmo método o "custo" de importação é o mesmo custo de criar uma nova variável, ou seja, quase nada.

A melhor prática cabe a você decidir. Por conta do guia de estilo eu coloco quase todas as importações no cabeçalho dos módulos. Mas nem sempre. Pode ser um pacote razoavelmente grande para importar que não será necessário em toda excecução do programa, por exemplo: uma função que exporta um gráfico e para isso importa o matplotlib. Mover a importação para dentro de um método nesse caso, faria o início do programa ser mais rápido, com a contrapartida de uma demora (sempre menor que 1s, em geral) quando a funcionalidade for usada a primeira vez.

Via de regra, se o seu programa é um serviço que funciona como um servidor, é melhor importar tudo no início, garantindo um tempo mínimo de espera em todas as requisições. Se for um programa interativo, pode ser interessante optar por ter um início mais rápido e ir fazendo algumas importações depois.

Em alguns projetos que os arquivos de testes ficam muito grandes, eu também opto por importar as funções/classes sendo testadas direto dentro das funções de testes, só para ficar mais visível  o que estou testando. (Mas uma reorganização poderia simplesmente quebrar tudo em arquivos menores, por exemplo).

E por fim, as vezes, por conta do próprio funcionamento do seu sistema, é *necessário* uma importação tardia de alguns módulos. É o caso d aplicações em Flask, por exemplo - em que é conveniente que  módulo `__init__`  tenha referências para as views, mas por outro lado, os arquivos de de view precisam ter uma referência ao objeto `app` defindo no próprio `__init__`. Em geral, isso se resolve importando as views no  `__init__` mais perto do final do arquivo, mas poderia ser dentro de uma função também.